# How to get http response status code from microservice - zuul [java]

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-zuul

I developed a `PreFilter` for `Zuul` which does some checks on a request containing a `JWT` and if every checks goes OK, routes the request to the target Microservice.

What I'd like to do is to get the response `HTTP` status code.

I'm trying to develop a `PostFilter` in charge of getting the `HTTP` status code, but I'm stuck on it.

```
public class PostFilter extends ZuulFilter {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "post";
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() throws ZuulException {

        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();

        HttpServletResponse response = ctx.getResponse();

        int statusCode = response.getStatus();

        System.out.println(statusCode);

        return null;
    }

}
```

The `System.out.println()` statement prints `0`.

How can I solve it? Thank you guys.

Comment: Are you sure that response is determined when zuulFilter is applied

Comment: I set the `filterOrder` to `2`, so It should be

Answer (score 0):

Instead use: `context.getResponseStatusCode()`